# I'm keep getting 502 gateway error (django)

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Would you please check my codes and tell me where does this error come form?

gunicorn.sevice file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/root/parsiproject
ExecStart=/root/parsiproject/parsiEnv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 
unix:/root/parsiproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:applicat$

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

nginx.conf file:

```
...
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 64.34.135.108;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
      root /root/parsiproject;
    }
   location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/root/parsiproject/myproject.sock;
}
...
```

nginx error.log:

```
2018/08/12 11:57:37 [crit] 3792#0: *35 connect() to 
unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or 
directory) w$
```

I've already inserted my server ip in setting.py allowed host.

Comment: the path /home/user/myproject does not have permission for anonymous user

Answer (score 0):

I guess your socket path is not proper and also the gunicorn service file is having issue. Also `myproject.wsgi:applicat$` should be `myproject.wsgi:application` I guess. Follow the below tutorial for creating the socket and all the path.

[Django setup tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Following is an example of the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=xyz django daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/services/xyz_backend/xyz_backend
ExecStart=/var/www/services/xyz_backend/xyz_python_env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/services/xyz_backend/xyz_backend/xyz.sock xyz_backend.wsgi:application
```